# Cost effective analytics platform

Tags: api, analytics

I am looking for a cost effective analytics platform (rather than have to write it myself).

I need a platform where I can configure calculations, where dependencies are worked out (and acted on) and that has a rich API so that I can upload raw data, download calculated data and obtain the status of the system. I would also like to perform aggregation on the data, preferably on the fly.

Excel is just not good enough and some of the platforms out there are just expensive so I am looking for a platform to support the work that I am doing that is not going to cost a huge amount of money.

Does anyone know where to look for this sort of thing? I am struggling but there must be something out there.

---

[Update]

a) I have a set of raw data and this raw data is updated periodically.

b) I want to perform a series of calculations on this raw data. Ideally, I would to have access to properties of the raw data so that I can change them and recalculate.

c) I would like to be able to configure new calculations and have a UI to view the output.

d) I would like an API to send in the raw data and extract calculated data.

Some of the solutions out there are very expensive but I don't want to write this myself. I need a cost effective product to do this.

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) This has the potential to be a good question (+1), but if you give more details, then you will get a better answer. Please read [ask]. Did you search our existing questions & answers?

Comment: I will try and explain what I am after:

a) I have a set of raw data and this raw data is updated periodically.
b) I want to perform a series of calculations on this raw data. Ideally, I would to have access to properties of the raw data so that I can change them and recalculate.
c) I would like to be able to configure new calculations and have a UI to view the output.
d) I would like an API to send in the raw data and extract calculated data.

Some of the solutions out there are very expensive but I don't want to write this myself. I need a cost effective produce to do this.

Comment: Not everyone reads the comments, so it is better to update the question (i have done that for you)

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I'd use Python with Pandas installed with the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/). However, that requires real programming (as does R) and may not be everyone's cup of tea. Another option I've dabbled with is [KNIME](https://www.knime.com/). It has a visual programming approach where you add icons for functionality and wire data flows. It looks pretty powerful and is fully open source and free. I believe it can handle all your requirements.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I cannot see how R can handle dependencies for me and only calculate data if necessary. I have years of data so this sort of efficiency is critical for me.

Comment: @Sputnik I'm not suggesting R, rd_nielson did. However, both R and Python are full fledged programming languages and are Turing complete. This means they can fully handle whatever algorithm you might envision. It also means you might have to write code yourself. KNIME also has a full complement of conditional expressions so I'm guessing it can do what you want too. That said, there may not be pre-written functions already there to use.

Answer (score 0):

The R language (https://www.r-project.org/) is widely used, has a massive library of code for all kinds of calculations, and is free.  Automation of calculations through scripting is likely to meet your needs for an API (given the limited description of your requirements).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I cannot see how R can handle dependencies for me and only calculate data if necessary. I have years of data so this sort of efficiency is critical for me.

Comment: @rd_neilsen I've already answered this identical comment to my answer. Essentially, R (and Python) are Turing complete and can calculate any algorithm. The user, however may need to learn to program.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using DataMelt from jwork.org. It is free platform and has 600 examples for data analysis posted on the web page.  In addition they recently posted full java api with description of 40k java classes. But you may need to learn python too since most of their examples are written in jython.